# Set visibility of dividers on a dynamic list

Tags: css, listitem

I am trying to recreate www.kotaku.co.uk front page. If you look at the footer on there specifically the 'Popular tags' list. From what I see it is a pretty standard list but the right hand item on each row has no dividing line. If you resize the window you can see how every item that is on the end of its row will have no dividing line.

Can someone tell me how they have the achieved this? I have tried using flexbox which got a pretty nice looking result but the sizing of each of the list items was a little too gappy in some instances. I've been scratching my head about this for a few days, its driving me mad.

Thanks
Ben

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm scratching my head, too, as to *why* it's happing like that, but I was able to narrow the code down to a combination of `display: inline` on the `li`'s and `display: inline-block` on the `a`'s inside of the `li`'s. Not sure what it is about that combo that disables the border of elements at the end of a row, but it does.

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
li {
  display: inline;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li><li><a href="#">asdf</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion.  Only addition is that they also add a `border:none` to `li:last-child`.  It's pretty puzzling.  I'm sure it's an obscure part of the spec.

Comment: @JosephMarikle yeah the `:last-child` is just for their display, doesn't seem to affect the last item of a row magic. Also just checked in FF and it doesn't happen there. Happens in safari tho, so it could be something based off of webkit? I wonder if it's a bug or if that's what's supposed to happen?